# LI elements have float left to be aligned to the right in a container?

Tags: html, css

In this code the LI elements have float:left and are aligned to the left of the container. I want to make them aligned to the right. How do I do this with CSS?

For example:
[..................................Item1.Item2]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. The order of LI's must not be reverse.

Comment: Have you tried `float: right`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu
{ float:right;
}
.menu li
{ float:left;
}
```

Or Use float:right to ul like

```
.menu ul
{ float:right;
}
.menu li
{ float:left;
}
```

JSFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SEAW5/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Make the `li`s inline and put `text-align:right` on the `ul`

```
.menu li {
    display:inline;  
}
.menu ul {
    text-align:right;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKARB/

Comment: he'll lose the list-style markers though. but i guess he doesn't want them anyway.

Comment: he flaoted them left so i assumed he didnt want the list style

Comment: This is the best solution. Also `display: inline-block;` will allow the LIs to have width/height.

Answer (score 0):

reverse the order of the `li`s in your html, and use `float: right`

Comment: It's impossible because the source of LI's is shared across multiple templates that may want the direct order of the items.

Comment: have you tried floating the `ul` right (within the wrapping div) ?

Comment: i mean use `float:left` on the `li`s and `float:right` on the `ul`. may work

Comment: Yes, I tried text-align:right for the container, the DIV. Does not work.

Comment: works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XZbNa/). of course, the div needs a fixed width. if you don't want that, you could pin your ul or div to the right side with `position: absolute` and `right: 0`

Comment: float:left on the lis and float:right on the ul worked, but is screwed up in IE8. Good idea anyway. Thank you.